# AWS login using username/password or social login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is it possible to, for an existing Cognito user pool user, allow that user to login in the future using a social login **or** their username/password?

For example, I make a user via social login, and later I want to choose whether to login using my social login or using a username and password, instead.

Is it possible to let a user choose, each time they log in, how to do it? How can I set this up in my Cognito user pool and auth flow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can, an example you can find it using the example :

https://itnext.io/facebook-login-using-aws-amplify-and-amazon-cognito-4acf74875a04

> Offering Both Facebook Login and Username/Password Options?
>   For most apps, developers should offer both a unique username/password authentication option along with a social identity login such as Facebook, Google, or Twitter. Why? First, not everyone has a Facebook or social media account. Second, those with an account, may not be comfortable associating their Facebook account with your app. Third, most users don’t want to create yet another password they can’t remember.

Comment: I don’t think this answers OP’s question, which seems to be *for the same user* can that user log in with both U/P and Facebook, alternating

Comment: @AWS PS Can I able to support instagram social login with aws-cognito

Comment: unfortunately No, you need to create your custom auth provider.

Comment: Can you explain a bit. How can I create custom auth provider? Any docs?